# Mocking ApiController which has Unit of work Dependency

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, nunit, asp.net-web-api, simple-injector

I have a `Apicontroller` Which has dependency on unit of work object. How to write a test case for mocking `ApiController` Which has dependency on unit of work implemented in `ApiController` constructor.

Here is the code:

ApiController:

```cs
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    public IUoW UoW { get; set; }
    // GET api/user
    public UserController(IUoW uow)
    {
        UoW = uow;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Users> Get()
    {
        return UoW.Users.Getall();
    }     
}
```

The Test case :

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void TestApiController()
{
    var userManager = new Mock<IUoW>();
    userManager.Setup(s => s.Users);

    var controller = new UserController(userManager.Object);
    var values = controller.Get();
    Assert.IsNotNull(values);
}
```

The Users Class which has been mentioned here in UoW.Users is

```cs
public class UoW:IUoW,IDisposable
{
    private MvcWebApiContext DbContext { get; set; }
    protected IRepositoryProvider RepositoryProvider { get; set; }

    private IRepository<T> GetStandardRepo<T>() where T : class
    {
        return RepositoryProvider.GetRepositoryForEntityType<T>();
    }

    public IRepository<Users> Users
    {
        get { return GetStandardRepo<Users>(); }
    }
}
```

and the `Users` class itself is

```cs
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class Users
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }


    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    public long Mobile { get; set; }
}
```

When I am trying to debug the test case , the Test case shows the object `UoW.Users` is null in `UserController`. Its obvious its not initializing through `WebActivator` since global.asax isnt invoked here through mock. Now how to write a successful test scenario in this context so that the `WebApicontroller` returns me the users object with data ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using Moq?

As I cannot see what type the `UoW.Users` property is I cannot demo how to mock it properly (*updated* IRepository) but that should be mocked and the GetAll method stubbed to return a sample list of users.

**Updated**

```
        var userManager = new Mock<IUoW>();

        userManager.Setup(s => s.Users).Returns(()=> 
        { 
            var userReposisitory = new Mock<IRepository<Users>>();

            userReposisitory.Setup(ur => ur.GetAll()).Returns(()=> {
                var listOfUsers = new List<Users>();
                listOfUsers.Add(new Users { FirstName = "Example" });
                return listOfUsers.AsQueryable();
            });

            return userReposisitory.Object; 
        });

        var controller = new UserController(userManager.Object);
        var result = controller.Get();
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        Assert.IsTrue(result.Count() > 0);
```

Comment: Oh okay !my bad I would include the Users class here . Please wait :)

Comment: @Joy - no worries. Answer updated. P.S. the class name "Users" is a tad confusing, suggest you make it singular "User".

Comment: No it didnt the lines `userManager.Setup(s => s.Users).Returns(new Mock<IRepository<Users>>());
    userManager.Users.Setup(s => s.GetAll()).Returns(listOfUsers)` are giving errors here . I cdnt reply since tht part is left in my office

Comment: @Joy - apologies, I really should have tested my code but was answering in a hurry last time. Updated now and confirmed to work.

Comment: Assert.That had to be changed since I was using inbuilt `UnitTesting` library. Another issue was it gives cannot implicitly convert `Generic.List<Users> to IQueryable<Users>` at `return listOfUsers.ToList();`

Comment: Sorry thought you were using NUnit although now I look it is clear you weren't. As for the IQueryable bit a very quick modification to add return listOfUsers.AsQueryable();